# Hotmail Contact Import Alternate PHP

Tags: php, api, hotmail

I got an old script working in local for importing hotmail email address. but can't find it working in live server. Says connection timeout.

Script total detail on: http://blog.outsourcingnepal.com/2013/02/importing-hotmail-contacts-via-php/

Comfortable with alternate idea too.

Comment: I assume you're asking someone for their primary Hotmail logon credentials? If so, whilst there are probably some limited cases where this might useful, in general it seems to be encouraging very poor security practices amongst your target users. Many people don't know that these details can be stored by whoever they supply them to indefinitely, and used for purposes that they would not knowingly authorise.

Comment: If your script works locally but not remotely, perhaps you need to configure a firewall to let the traffic out? Port 1863 may be blocked. You may need to talk to your host about that. Are you on a shared server?

Comment: Definitely the points you pointed are good @halfer. I keep that in mind. Regardig Outgoing port, thanks for the firewall idea. I had forgot that. Checking it now.

Comment: Thanks @halfer, Your firewall stuff worked for me. Opened the port and worked like magic... Thanks.

Comment: No problem, answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment: if your script works locally but not remotely, sounds like the script it having trouble getting past a firewall on your side. If you create a rule in your firewall so that it lets out traffic on 1863, you should be good to go.